# Можно ли в json вложить еще один json?

Tags: json

Можно ли отправляя json вложить в него еще один json?

Comment: трудно сказать можно ли в вашем случае это сделать, но вообще - да, можно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример json в json

```
{"menu": {
    "id": "file",
    "value": "File",
    "popup": {
        "menuitem": [
           {"value": "New", "onclick": "test()"},
           {"value": "Open", "onclick": "test()"},
           {"value": "Close", "onclick": "test()"}
        ]
    }
}}
```

Comment: здесь же только один json, где вложенный?

Comment: {"value": "Close", "onclick": "test()"} Чем вам не json?

Comment: Технически, даже `[null]` это JSON в JSON.

Answer (score -1):

Да, можно отправляя json вложить в него еще один json